# How to add vertical scrollbar to the table sent by python email module?

Tags: python, html, email, scrollbar

I have a very long dataframe that sent by python email module. I want it have a vertical scrollbar so that the whole email looks tight. But I am not familar with HTML, not sure where to put the *div style="overflow-y: auto;"* part

Following is the html code.

```
email_html = """\
<html>
  <head>
      Dear all, <br>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
       1.Cash Flow <br>
    </p>  
       <div style="overflow-y: auto;">
       {0}
       </div>       
    <p>   
       Regards,
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
""".format(table_in_html_format)
```

It just generates simple plain table in email like this, no scrollbar attached.

[image]

Thank you ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should set a obvious height value to that `div`

```html
email_html = """\
<html>
  <head>
      Dear all, <br>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
       1.Cash Flow <br>
    </p>  
       <div style="overflow-y: auto;height:100px">
       {0}
       </div>       
    <p>   
       Regards,
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
""".format(table_in_html_format)
```